# How to parse dynamic json formatted kafka message in spark streaming

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm implementing a Spark Structured Streaming job where I'm consuming messages coming from Kafka in JSON format.

Since the json data is dynamic I do not have the schema information to use in the **from_json** function to load the json data to spark dataframe

Below is the code I have used to read the data from kafka topic

```
df = spark_session.readStream.format("kafka") \
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "...") \
      .option("subscribe", "..") \
      .option("startingTimestamp", "...").load()
```

How can I use the below **from_json** function or if any other functions available to load the json data into dataframe without predefined schema

```
df = df.select(from_json(col("value").cast("string")).alias("parsed_value"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd use `get_json_object(column, '<json path>')`  to parse string typed json columns

Comment: Thanks for the reply  in ```get_json_object(column, '<json path>')``` function I have the column parameter with string formatted json structure , what is the '<json path>' I have to use?

Comment: I don't know what your records look like to answer that. Refer the docs for examples https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.get_json_object.html#pyspark.sql.functions.get_json_object